# After the first answer, Prolog shows the error "char_code/2: Cannot represent due to 'character_code'"

Tags: prolog, swi-prolog, prolog-toplevel

In normal situation, we can use `";"` to show the next answer if there is one.
But if I do this, it shows me

```
error: char_code/2: Cannot represent due to 'character_code'
```

In stead of `";"`, I use `"shift + ;"`, and prolog gives me a prompt

```
Unknown action: : (h for help)   Action?
```

then if I input `";"`, the designable answers will be shown one by one.

What is the problem?

Comment: What happens if you use the spacebar instead ? Also my keyboard need shift to emit ';' .

Comment: Does your program do a `read`?

Comment: Please show us the code.

Answer (score 3):

Use swipl-win.exe instead of swipl.exe can solve this problem.(I tried 6.x and 7.x)

By the way, swipl works well under MacOS.